# ASP.NET MVC Validation - Clarifying validation messages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

Consider this model class:

```
public class FooModel {
     public Person Manager { get; set; }
     public Person Employee { get; set; }
}

public class Person {
     [Required]
     public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

If the user provides a `Name` value in a form for the Manager but not the Employee then the `ValidationSummary()` will return the message "Name is required" without qualifying it further (i.e. it isn't clear that `Employee.Name` isn't set but `Manager.Name` is).

What solutions are there to this problem?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859658/how-do-i-show-a-different-required-message-to-instances-of-the-same-object-in-mv

Comment: Also as a note, when declaring the Person classes you are not supposed to use the keyword class. It should look like this: `public Person Manager { get; set; }`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question here: ( [How do I show a different Required message to instances of the same object in MVC3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859658/how-do-i-show-a-different-required-message-to-instances-of-the-same-object-in-mv) ) has two answers.

The first suggests flattening the ViewModel, in my case that would mean copying the `Person` members into `FooModel` twice, then I could set a customized validation message for both. I decided against this for obvious reasons (my `Person` class is considerably more complicated and also used elsewhere).

The second answer suggests modifying ModelState's error messages, which is what I do. I've already developed a way for ViewModels to modify their own validation so adding this trick was easy enough. I've added a [DisplayName] attribute like so (psuedocode):

```
class FooModel : ICustomValidation {
    [DisplayName("Manager")]
    public Person Manager { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Employee")]
    public Person Employee { get; set; }

    public void HandleValidation(ModelStateDictionary modelState) {
        if( modelState.IsInvalidByPrefix("Manager") ) {
            modelState.AppendErrorMessageDisplayPrefix( GetLocalisedDisplayName("Manager") );
        }
```

if( modelState.IsInvalidByPrefix("Employee") ) {
                modelState.AppendErrorMessageDisplayPrefix( GetLocalisedDisplayName("Employee") );
            }
        }
    }