# MVC Validation from one model to multiple views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I have a problem where I have one Model with validation and need certain error messages to show on different views. At the moment I get validation errors on all views for everything in my Model.

Im guessing there is a way to set individual validation messages depending on which view is showing?

My Model is as follows:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirm name of item")]
public string ItemName { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirm Number of items")]
public int NumberOfItems { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary()
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name:</td> <td>@Html.TextBox("ItemsName")</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Number:</td> <td>@Html.TextBox("NumberOfItems")</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I only need one error message showing on another view I have which only has the item name....

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, what's the problem on that other View? Just omit the number part.

Comment: Do you mean something like @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemName)?

Comment: I think the best way to achieve this would be a seperate ViewModel for each of your pages with a different error message

Comment: See this link for something similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859658/how-do-i-show-a-different-required-message-to-instances-of-the-same-object-in-mv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a seperate ViewModel for every page.

You will not want to send the entire Model (which will most likely map to a database table through maybe an ORM) to your View. But create ViewModels for every page, which allows for View specific attributes and transforms for in the future (like dates, currencies, calculations, etc).

Comment: brilliant thanks everyone for your help! I have created seperate ViewModels for each page and it works well - Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to do this is to have one model for each view, because each view has different validation requirements.

Data annotation validations are statically compiled into your model and cannot be changed at runtime.  This is why you need a separate model for each view.

You can get around this somewhat by having a common view model, and then using a separate Metadata model for each view.  These are often called "buddy classes".

These are described here:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-(data)/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs